# get result of query step by step codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to do something like this:

```
if (isset($account)) {
    $this->db->where('account', $account);
}

if (isset($subject)) {
    $this->db->where('subject', $subject);
}

if (isset($contact)) {
    $this->db->where('_from', $contact);
}
//here i need to get result
$resul1 = $this->db->get('table');

$limit = 5; $offset =10;
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
//here i need to get result with offset and limit
$result2 = $this->db->get('table');
```

$result1 should execute this query

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `account` = 'some account'
AND `subject` = 'some subject'
AND `_from` = 'name'
```

and $result2 should execute this query ($query1 + offset and limit):

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `account` = 'some account'
AND `subject` = 'some subject'
AND `_from` = 'name'
LIMIT 10, 5
```

but `$result2` execute as a separate query: `select * FROM table LIMIT10, 5`

is it possible to achieve this or I need to start the query from the begining?

Comment: I would be useful to know why you would want to execute two queries when it seems that one would suffice.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746425/codeigniter-pagination-run-the-query-twice

Comment: @Jamie_D I need to determine max page number. i'm developing a rest api service so i cannot use CI pagination library.

Comment: @u_mulder it sounds it's not possible (at least in CI2).

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT Without limit() Function

```
result = $this->db->get('table', 0, $offset);
```

Or using manual select:

```
$query = "SELECT *, COUNT(account) AS total FROM `table` WHERE `account` = ? AND `subject` = ? AND `_from` = ? LIMIT 0, ?";
$result = $this->db->query($query, array($account, $subject, $contact, $offset));
```

Comment: this query just executes simple select without any `WHERE`. other conditions (account, subject, contact) must be considered

Comment: account, subject, contact are replaced with the conditions array (indicated in the result) See $this->db->query() With Query Bindings [link]http://www.bsourcecode.com/codeigniter/codeigniter-select-query/

Comment: Here's  better documentation to explain query bindings. See the bottom of this page:  [link]https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/queries.html

Comment: I think there is no way to do exactly what I want to do. I solved it by rejax (removing `LIMIT (digit)` and everything after it.